# How to set links to open bootstrap 4 modal until the final date of jQuery.countdown, and link to their urls once countdown is finished?

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation with two external links.

```
<nav class="app-links">
  <a href="https://www.apple.com/lae/ios/app-store/" class="apple"><img src="img/badge-apple-appstore.svg" alt="apple app store"></a>
  <a href="https://play.google.com/store?hl=en/" class="google"><img src="img/badge-google-play.svg" alt="google play store"></a>
</nav>
```

I'm using http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ plugin to generate the countdown timer inside a bootstrap modal.
Until the countdown timer is counting down to a set date I need to prevent the external links from linking to their urls and instead open the bootstrap 4 modal. When the countdown is finished they should link to the urls again.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

At the moment modal is set to open on page load and hide when countdown timer expires because I don't know how to set it to be triggered by the navigation links while the timer countdown is active.

```
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var finalDate = '2018/03/28 13:53:30';

        $('#timer').countdown(finalDate)
            .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
                + '<p><span>%-D</span>days</p>'
                + '<p><span>%H</span>hours</p>'
                + '<p><span>%-M</span>minutes</p>'));
            })
            .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can add a click event listener to your anchors in order to prevent the default action.
According to the [documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html) you can use the **elapsed** property to test if the counter is ended. When this happens you can enable again the anchors (remove the previous click handler).

```js
$('.app-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').modal('show');
})
var nowPlus2 = new Date();
nowPlus2.setMinutes(nowPlus2.getMinutes() + 1);
var finalDate = nowPlus2;

$('#timer').countdown(finalDate)
        .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            if (event.elapsed) {
                $('.app-links a').off('click');
            }
            $(this).text(event.strftime('%-D days %H hours %-M minutes %-S seconds'));
        })
        .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
            $('.app-links a').off('click');
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.0/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/master/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>


<nav class="app-links">
    <a href="https://www.apple.com/lae/ios/app-store/" class="apple"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=app+store" alt="apple app store"></a>
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store?hl=en/" class="google"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=google+play" alt="google play store"></a>
</nav>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Wait for...</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="timer"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```